# REGEX and RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm hoping to gain some insight on how best to set up a whole lot of URL redirects.
Because the URLs use a dynamic id, a regular Redirect permanent doesn’t seem to work for us. 
So I've tried a rewrite rule, which seems to work.

We're hoping to clean up a few strings like this:

```
/myolddirectory/olddir/oldfile.php?id=2 should redirect to: /mynewdirectory?id=2
/myolddirectory/olddir/oldfile.php?id=4 should redirect to: /mynewdirectory?id=4
```

This works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id\=2($|&)
RewriteRule ^myolddirectory/olddir/oldfile\.php$ /attra-pub-summaries?id=2 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id\=4($|&)
RewriteRule ^myolddirectory/olddir/oldfile\.php$ /attra-pub-summaries?id=4 [L,R]
```

We have some 600 ids.
I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this w/o having to write 600+ rules. Thank you.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^myolddirectory/olddir/oldfile\.php$ /attra-pub-summaries [L,QSA]` ? QSA save query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using one condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=([24])\b
RewriteRule ^myolddirectory/olddir/oldfile\.php$ /attra-pub-summaries?id=%1 [L,R]
```

`%1` refers to value held by first capturing group in rewrite condition.

Comment: This worked a treat for me! Thank you! Instead of ([24]) I used ([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) to match for any number from 0-999. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Lewisandclark200 To match any number from 0 to 999 you could use `(?!0.)\d{1,3}` in the rewrite  condition `\bid=((?!0.)\d{1,3})\b`

Comment: Much cleaner! I used it and it works swell. Thanks again revo. :-)